# How do you generate a private key from a seed phrase?

Tags: private-key

Without using a library or tool, is it possible to do this in excel for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will basically need the used word list and you should be able to do it in Excel just fine.

All the specifications are here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki . An example for example here: https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Comment: This is great! thanks so much!